# How do I click "Copy" using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriver

How do I click the "Copy" button from this URL https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/basic/java-basic-exercise-249.php
[image]

The tag I need to click is tagged as "Copy"

I have tried multiple "find element by" methods however I keep getting errors such as no such element.

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('toolbar-item') #not working
driver.findElementByClassName("a.cc_btn.cc_btn_accept_all") #not working
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("toolbar").click() #not working
driver.findElementByClassName("toolbar-item").click() #not working
```

In this case how to I select the "Copy" ref and what method is used to click "Copy"?
Further, when the "Copy" button is clicked, how can I paste the contents to a text file.

These are the other errors I get.

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 27, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("toolbar-item").click()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"toolbar-item"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

Also:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the `Copy` button induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `presence_of_element_located`() and following xpath.You need to scroll the element to click.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/basic/java-basic-exercise-249.php")
copybtn=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Copy']")))
copybtn.location_once_scrolled_into_view
copybtn.click()
```

---

You can use following css selector as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/basic/java-basic-exercise-249.php")
copybtn=WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".toolbar-item>a")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", copybtn)
copybtn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to post the Java equivalent to click the "Copy" button? :)